# Filling data for layout on each page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

We have a website that has a layout in which you could change: title page, breadcrumb, a short description, an icon on the header and other elements that are specific for each page.

We do this by:

- defining in each controller that info (as it is dynamic based on the page/model we show)
- sending to the view
- in the view we set with section those snippets that are declared with @yield in the layout blade.

It looks a little bit verbose. Is there any pattern that we should apply?

### layout.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('html.title')</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>@yield('body.title')</h1>
<article>
 @yield('body.content')
</article>
</body>
```

### controller.php

```
function index(){
$config['title']='Title tag';
$config['h1]='H1 Title tag';

return view('index',compact('config'));
}
```

### index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('html.title',$config['title']);
@section('body.title',$config['h1']);

@section('body.content')
this is tje page content
@endsection
```

Think that you would have to define 6-7 snippets like this for each page. I am thinking that is's too verbose for the Controller, as the Controller is only to pass the request to necessary services in order to return the right view.

Comment: Plese post your code along side the explanation, because it will be easier to see what you consider to be verbose.

Comment: Also, this isn't really a specific *problem*, but sounds like recommendations on design principles, which isn't the right kind of question for SO.

Comment: @TimLewis: I added more info. It might be a design principle , but my problem is that I do not know how can  I access data  other than coming from the controller.  I think that is my problem.

Comment: Other than coming from the controller? I don't think I follow...  You seem to be using the controller to define each page's `@section()`'s, but this doesn't seem right. I use a similar approach to my application design, but I have many files that extend `layout.blade.php`, each with their own `@section("title")` and `@section("content")`, etc. So, instead of having `@section("title", $config["title"])` I would have `@section("title") This is my Index Title @stop` on the actual `index.blade.php`. Also, side note, `@endsection` is technically deprecated in Laravel 5.0+

Comment: @TimLewis: I get your point. So if you need to generate dynamic (based on some rules): "This is my Index Title", where do you define it? In the controller? In the view?

Comment: Either, to be honest. Personally, anything to do with the backend (queries, etc) should be done on the controller. Checking a configuration variable can be done on the controller, but you'd then have to pass it to the view, which would be adding a step. But I don't think there's a *right* answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to try to put those things in the view - the title of the page seems to me to be much more part of the presentation than part of the data. For example, I have a `cancel.blade.php` file like this:

```
@extends("templates.core",[
    "title"=>"Cancel My Account",
    "description"=>"We're sad that you're leaving"
])


@section('content')
   ... stuff here ...
@stop
```

Comment: I did not know the second parameter of extends...that would shorten some of the codel ike this : @extends("layout,$layoutSnippets);